# Clustering based on euclidean distance in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a big innodb table with arrays of data (saved as binary). The table is indexed only by timestamp.
I do query in batches (mysql ss cursor), and for every batch I convert arrays to floats and calculate euclidean distance like this:

*numpy.linalg.norm(y-x, axis=1)*

Where y is the array that I'm using to find closest to.
And x is list of arrays from mysql.

It works fine except it's slow for long queires. So I'm asking some advice how can I select only arrays which are closest to the target array and cut very different from the query. I suppose I should compute some value for each array in parsing time and save it along with the array, so then my query should look like:

*SELECT row_id, array WHERE array_value BETWEEN N AND F;* (indexed by array_value)

I suppose the query should give me similar (but not preciesly) arrays and after that I can compute exact distance as I did before with numpy.linalg.norm

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I know zilch about numpy.  Please explain in English or Mathematics or Geometry what the goal is.  And how is an _array_ "close" to something?  MySQL has no "arrays" other than "rows".

Comment: @RickJames the goal is to get arrays with similar distance, example for 3 dimention:
import math
x = (5, 6, 7)
y = (8, 9, 9)
distance = math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(x, y)]))

Comment: @RickJames but the problem is that my arrays are long (I cannot use 3 columns). So I'm looking for a way to query for similar arrays (to reduce query size).

Comment: @RickJames arrays are saved as binary data, I decode every batch before search.

Comment: So, your "array" column is just a binary blob?  MySQL can't do any computations on that.  Why would you store it that way instead of columns of floats?

Comment: @TimRoberts because it's long, every array contains 128 numbers.

Comment: 128 columns is no big deal for MySQL, and then you would have its complete power for doing searches and queries.

Comment: It sounds like the process involves fetching every byte from the table and using it in the computation.  So, the question is "what is a better algorithm" -- namely one that does not need to use that much data or do that much computing.

Comment: @RickJames thanks, that's what I'm trying to reduce data from query. The problem is rather to find the closest arrays for the array (matching arrays).

Comment: A tiny optimization is to avoid the `SQRT`, assuming it is practical to simply work with the squares of the distances.

Answer (score 0):

Is your "array" 3 elements long?  Namely (x,y,z)?  Let's call that a "POINT".

Is "closest" measured by Euclidean distance?

The simplest algorithm is to check the distance to every Point.  This is time-consuming.  The next best is to build a "bounding box" around the target Point.  That is, see if there are any points that match this, and if so, which is the closest:

```
xi - eps < x < xi + eps AND
yi - eps < y < yi + eps AND
zi - eps < z < zi + eps
```

If you find no Points, increase `eps` and try again.  (So, it is best to pick `eps` so that you are likely to find an answer on the first try, but not so big that you don't save much time relative to scanning all Points.)

Given that that is a restatement of your problem, but closer to what MySQL understands, then...

```
CREATE TABLE points (
    id ...,
    ts TIMESTAMP ...,   -- since you mentioned this
    x INT ...,   -- Or maybe FLOAT?
    y ...,
    z ..., 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    INDEX(timestamp),
    INDEX(x,y,z)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then the query is something like

```
SET @x = 11, @y = 22, @z = 33;  -- the target "point"
SET @eps = 5;
SELECT  *,
        SQRT( (x - @x) * (x - @x) +
              (y - @y) * (y - @y)
              (z - @z) * (z - @z) ) AS distance
    FROM points
    WHERE  x BETWEEN @x - @eps AND @x + @eps
      AND  y BETWEEN @y - @eps AND @y + @eps
      AND  z BETWEEN @z - @eps AND @z + @eps
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1   -- assuming you want only the closest.
```

More discussion [*here*](HTTP://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql) .

**Not useful**

While what I said above is useful in some contexts, it does not scale beyond 2 or 3 dimensions.  I would expect it to be essentially useless for 128 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks but my arrays are 128 elements long. I was trying to save arrays as json and tried similar things.

Comment: @Kirimaks -  You mean 128 "dimensions", not just 2 or 3?  Cluster analysis is rather complex.  FIrst find an algorithm that avoids checking all points in the universe.  Then we can discuss how to implement that in python+mysql.

Comment: yes, every array contains 128 floats. To make it more clear, here is function in c++ which is used for comparison https://gist.github.com/kirimaks/f117898a6f88accd7dc381fab97d52d1 
Basically numpy.linalg.norm is doing the same thing but it allows to compare for many arrays at once (so I don't have to iterate over a big list)

Comment: What I was hoping to do is to be able to compute some kind of "weight" for every array before I save it to database. Then my database would be kind of "clustered" by array weight. So later when I need to do a query, I would calcuate "weight" for my target array, and make db query for arrays with same "weight" or similar "weights" and I hope that would make my query shorter. (and "weight" column is indexed of course)

Comment: @Kirimaks - I'm still struggling with understanding the "physics" behind the problem.  I have no problem generalizing "find nearest" in 2 or 3 dimensions to 128 'dimensions'.  Now I don't have a model of where "weight" comes into play.  Is it like "gravity" in astronomical (3D) models?  Or maybe giving preference to "heavy" points (aka 'arrays')?

Comment: Yes the distance computation for 2 or 128 dimensional should be the same but for example  if i want to search “nearest” for today the problem is that i may have 1m arrays for today and maybe only 5 are matching, so in this case i have to pull out the whole 1m to search.

Comment: So what im trying to do is to find a way to query fo kind of similar arrays (to the target array) similar but not precise (to have smaller amount of data to search in). To be able to do that i need to have some column in database which will represent some kind of cluster. And on search I would pull out a cluster instead of 1m.

Comment: For example i could cluster the whole table with kmeans clustering. Then put cluster number for every array. So on query i would use cluster number to get results. (Of course I would need to find a cluster at first but it’s another story). Btw kmeans doesnt work for me because need to load all data to memory for clustering, also new data coming very quickly so I would need to rebuild it which is expensive.

Comment: @Kirimaks - Thanks for the tip "k-means".  How many vectors (points) to start with?  How fast are new ones coming in?  How many clusters do you anticipate?

Comment: The table is big (hundreds of millions) also new data coming very fast (almost every second). I would expect not a big number of clusters because if I would do in this way then I should find the cluster at first.

Comment: Also found some library https://nanopq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/tutorial.html
It implements ANN algorithm, it works but it loses precision and there is no way to append new data. Also uses k-means clustering.

Comment: @Kirimaks - If there were 100K clusters, it seems like you might be able to find which cluster's centroid a new array is closest to within a second.  Note: this task could be broken into as many threads as you have CPUs.  Then hand that off to another process to decide whether the cluster should be split.  Or maybe it is 'between' two clusters and takes more effort to decide where to put the new array.

Comment: I found another problem. My query is getting slow because of blob column, I converted it to varchar but it's still slow.